# Unpacking and configuring kvm components

Tags: kvm-virtualization, chromebook, chromeos, crouton

In this guide : http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/RunningKVM

It says "If you are using a recent kernel (2.6.25+) with kvm modules included, boot into it"

What does it mean boot into the kernal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu (and other distributions) can have multiple kernel versions installed but you can only (directly) use one at the time. The version is selected by the bootloader. I'm not sure if this applies to Chromebooks but on a normal PC, you'd hold <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> before Ubuntu loads and that'll show you the Grub bootloader and give you choices about which Kernel version you'd load.

But that's all academic for your purposes.

- 2.6 is ancient. Modern Ubuntu is on 4.x kernels. You're okay here.
- Use distribution-specific documentation. You don't have to download and compile KVM support yourself. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM

Comment: Thanks, it says /dev/kvm is missing, and I was reading another guide that made it seem like the chroot doesnt have the kvm packages. All doc I've found so far has been ubuntu specific, I repackaged my ChromeOS kernal to enable vmx in bios, but donno how to get the actual module in my chroot

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/i-can't-get-kvm-working-fatal-module-kvm_intel-not-found-4175497614/

I have 14.04 on the chroot, I seem to have a similar problem as the person in the link above

Comment: I am still struggling with this, I made a new question here 
: http://askubuntu.com/questions/757552/kvm-on-a-trusty-chroot